# How to upload OneSignal SDK file in node js?

Tags: node.js, onesignal

I want to use web push notification using onesignal. I create account on onsignal.com and i follow the steps (I choose chrome web push). But on step six is "Upload OneSignal SDK file". I download the files and i read the documentations but i couldn't understand it. I am using web app created on node js. Bellow I put the link of step 6 from OneSignal documentations.

*https://documentation.onesignal.com/docs/web-push-typical-setup#section--span-class-step-step-6-span-upload-onesignal-sdk*

Any help please. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Actually it was simple, I was just confused and forgot some terms on node js. After some fight i fix it.

I just need to put the Unzipped file in my working directory (main root). Then make it publicly available. Simply like this, then it works.

```
app.use(express.static(path.("foldername")));
```